# Using Categories To Add Methods That Take Blocks In Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I figured this should be easy, but I am having problems writing a simple class level category method that takes a block for an argument. Here is my example while trying to add a class method to NSAutoreleasePool.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSAutoreleasePool (MyBlockAdditions)
+ (void)forWork: (void (^)(void))work;
@end

#import "NSAutoreleasePool+MetaSkillsAdditions.h"
@implementation NSAutoreleasePool (MyBlockAdditions)
+ (void)forWork: (void (^)(void))work {
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  work();
  [pool release];
}
@end

[NSAutoreleasePool forWork:^{
  ...
}];
```

I am currently getting this error now. I am likely doing something dumb.

```
2011-03-05 16:17:49.150 MyApp[28100:40b] +[NSAutoreleasePool forWork:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xb20598
2011-03-05 16:17:49.154 MyApp[28100:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSAutoreleasePool forWork:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xb20598'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the category header file (`NSAutoreleasePool+MetaSkillsAdditions.h`) to the file containing the code that calls the new method?

Comment: Not importing the header would cause a compile-time warning, but is irrelevant to the runtime error being reported.

Comment: Yea, it is something with my crazy shared code structure. Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me. Are you sure that the file implementing the category is actually being compiled into the app?